# ext.js combobox how do I stop it appending stuff to my query string?

Tags: extjs

I am using ext.js combobox, I want to have a complete control over the query string, it is already generated dynamically. However, ext.js automatically append something to the string, like &query=leaf%20&page=1&start=0&limit=25. The server I am working with will fail if some parameters are not recognized. Is there a way to turn this off? Thanks,

Comment: set "queryParam" in the config object to a falsy value can turn of the query parameter.

Comment: for others, need to set them in the store config object (instead of combo box config object) to falsy values to turn them off.